# Is it possible to have multiple segments for same component in Ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have been trying to load the same component, based on different segments. However, it always takes me to only one segment. The code is as below:

In app.module.ts, the links were defined as follows:

```
 links: [
        { component: LoginPage, name: 'LoginPage', segment: 'login' },
        { component: HomePage, name: 'HomePage', segment: 'home' },
        { component: Filter, name: 'ScheduleFilter', segment: 'scheduleFilter' },
        { component: PickPage, name: 'PickPage', segment: 'pick/orders/cold/team/:team/cluster/:cluster' },
        { component: PickPage, name: 'PickPage', segment: 'pick/orders/cold/team//cluster/' },
        { component: PickPage, name: 'PickPage', segment: 'pick/orders/ambient/team/:team' },
        { component: PickPage, name: 'PickPage', segment: 'pick/orders/cold/team/' },
        { component: PickPage, name: 'PickPage', segment: 'pick/baskets/team/' },
        { component: PickPage, name: 'PickPage', segment: 'pick/baskets/team/:team' }
      ]
```

and in tabs routing part, there were defined as this:

```
{ title: 'Pick Baskets (Ambient)', icon: 'calendar', segment: '/pick/baskets/team/:team/', component: PickPage },
{ title: 'Pick Orders (Ambient)', icon: 'contacts' , segment: '/pick/orders/ambient/team/:team/', component: PickPage },
{ title: 'Pick Orders (Cold)', icon: 'map', segment: '/pick/orders/cold/team/:team/cluster/:cluster', component: PickPage },
```

But whatever tab I click, the URL ends up as /pick/baskets/team/:team

Am I doing something wrong here? I am just a novice to Ionic, and unable to figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think [Ionic page](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/) would help you

Comment: Hi Shivi, late reply but I've bumped into this and the solution is on the [ionicframework forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionicpage-more-than-one-parameter/91996/6)